# XSLT Element Alignment in output

Tags: xslt, format

Trying to solve an issue for someone else and instead have run into my own odd issue which I  am sure is simple yet the answer is eluding me!

The XML I have:

```
<xml>
  <head>
    <info>
      <content>
        <source attribute1="RSC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)">
          data1
        </source>
        <cite/>
        <case/>
        (
        <target attribute1="LRC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)1">
          3e/191
        </target>
        )
      </content>
      <content>
        <source attribute1="RSC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)">
          data2
        </source>
        <cite/>
        <case/>
        (
        <target attribute1="LRC1985s5c4" attribute2="6(17)1">
          4e/54
        </target>
        )
      </content>
    </info>
  </head>
</xml>
```

With XSLT to combine the two content elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="info">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="content">
        <xsl:for-each select="content">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This creates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml> //Just noticed here too!
  <head>
    <info><content> //Why no new line here?
        <source attribute1="RSC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)">
          data1
        </source>
        <cite />
        <case />
        (
        <target attribute1="LRC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)1">
          3e/191
        </target>
        )

        <source attribute1="RSC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)">
          data2
        </source>
        <cite />
        <case />
        (
        <target attribute1="LRC1985s5c4" attribute2="6(17)1">
          4e/54
        </target>
        )
      </content></info> //And again here?
  </head>
</xml>
```

The issue highlighted using commenting is what I cannot figure out, why there is no new line between the elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With the provided transformation slightly modified**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="info">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="content">
        <xsl:for-each select="content">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I get with Saxon 6.5.5 and a number of other XSLT 1.0 processors a well-indented output:**

```
<xml>
   <head>
      <info>
         <content>
            <source attribute1="RSC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)">
          data1
        </source>
            <cite/>
            <case/>
        (
        <target attribute1="LRC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)1">
          3e/191
        </target>
        )
      <source attribute1="RSC1985s5c1" attribute2="6(17)">
          data2
        </source>
            <cite/>
            <case/>
        (
        <target attribute1="LRC1985s5c4" attribute2="6(17)1">
          4e/54
        </target>
        )
      </content>
      </info>
   </head>
</xml>
```

**Some XSLT processors may still produce unwanted-indentation** -- there is no strict standard in the W3C XSLT 1.0 recommendation how exactly indentation should be performed.

Comment: Works as wanted, my processor does the indentation of the empty elements slightly differently but thats Microsoft for you. Quick perfect answer as per usual from you!